# Performance benefits of predict_batch_udf over a Pandas UDF?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Are there any performance benefits to using [`predict_batch_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.functions.predict_batch_udf.html) over creating a [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html)?

It does expose a `batch_size` parameter but is this any different from adjusting `spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch` to control the Pandas UDF batch sizes?